# Keycloak is calling the wrong auth url after changing the domain name

Tags: keycloak

After changing the domain name, Keycloak is still trying to authenticate using the old domain name. I'm using the Keycloak version 16.1 with KeycloakJS on the frontend using PKCE, on a server that runs everything in docker containers behind an Nginx reverse proxy.

I have changed all the references of the old domain to the new one, but it still redirects to the old domain:

https://auth.old-domain.com/auth/realms/dev-realm/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html

All the other resources are requested from the new domain, except the **step1.html**, which is calling the above link.

[image]

Any idea of what may be the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It's not related to Keycloak.
Even though I have changed the auth URL in the frontend application to the new domain, the CI/CD pipeline wasn't updating the docker image for the frontend application, so it used the old image that had the reference to the old domain.